# Как перемножить два 24-битных числа на ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Как перемножить два 24-битных числа на ассемблере?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аналогично сложению. К тому же наиболее эффективный алгоритм зависит от разрядности процессора. Еще могу привести такой вариант:

```
ABC * DEF = (A << 16 + BC) * (D << 16 + EF) = A * D << 32 + BC * D << 16 + A * EF << 16 + BC * EF
```

Отдельными буквами указаны 8-битные части числа. Складывать числа Вы уже умеете :-)

Comment: понятно, большое спасибо